# Creating Openshift BuildConfig with inline Dockerfile definition

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openshift, buildconfig

I'm following the steps in [this link](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/viewdocument/lightweight-approach-to-create-a-cu?CommunityKey=77544459-9fda-40da-ae0b-fc8c76f0ce18&tab=librarydocuments) to create a BuildConfig on Openshift Cluster running eus v4.12

The tutorial uses inline Dockerfile definition in the step of creating the BuildConfig, I followed the tutorial but in this step it returned the error

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml:line14: could not find expected
> ':'

BuildConfig definition:

```
oc apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
 name: my-custom-ace-image
 namespace: ${OPEN_SHIFT_PROJECT}
 labels:
 name: my-custom-ace-image
spec:
 triggers: []
 source:
 type: dockerfile
 dockerfile: |
 FROM ace-server-prod:latest-amd64
 COPY HTTPEcho.bar /home/aceuser/initial-config/bars/HTTPEcho.bar
 strategy:
 type: Docker
 dockerStrategy:
 from:
 kind: ImageStreamTag
 name: 'ace-server-prod:latest-amd64'
 namespace: ${OPEN_SHIFT_PROJECT} 
 output:
 to:
 kind: ImageStreamTag
 name: 'my-custom-ace-image:latest-amd64'
 namespace: ${OPEN_SHIFT_PROJECT}
EOF
```

Comment: There are a variety of syntax problems with the YAML you've posted in your question. Use a site like https://www.yamllint.com/ to identify them, fix the syntax, and see if that resolves your problem.